# Login with gmail and OmniAuth in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, google-openid

I am trying login with gmail and OmniAuth in rails 3. I am following http://hoisie.com/2011/09/12/using-google-oauth-with-omniauth/ this post. I added `gem 'omniauth'`
 in my gem file. Create omniauth.rb inside initializers. Replace the `oauth_secret` by API key generated in google api site.

Create sessions controller and adding

```
match "/auth/:provider/callback" => "sessions#create"
match "/signout" => "sessions#destroy", :as => :signout
```

this in my route.rb

When i am running the app getting the following error.

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/omniauth-1.0.1/lib/omniauth/builder.rb:25:in `provider': Could not find matching strategy for :google. You may need to install an additional gem (such as omniauth-google). (LoadError)
```

Answer (score 3):

There is an omniauth strategy for Google, it is [omniauth-google-oauth2](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2). Just just add it to your `Gemfile` as you are adviced in the error message.

You may also want to look at my [example app](https://github.com/maprihoda/primal_auth) that includes authenticating via omniauth.